# Jquery character count not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, acts-as-commentable

Jquery character counts aren't showing under my comment forms, even though they work for my other forms. Any help is appreciated.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <div class="titlecountdown"></div>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <div class="contentcountdown"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

custom.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  updateTitleCountdown = ->
    remaining = 20 - jQuery("#comment_title").val().length
    jQuery(".titlecountdown").text remaining + " characters remaining"

  jQuery ->
    updateTitleCountdown()
    $("#comment_title").change updateTitleCountdown
    $("#comment_title").keyup updateTitleCountdown

$ ->
  updateContentCountdown = ->
    remaining = 120 - jQuery("#comment_content").val().length
    jQuery(".contentcountdown").text remaining + " characters remaining"

  jQuery ->
    updateContentCountdown()
    $("#comment_content").change updateContentCountdown
    $("#comment_content").keyup updateContentCountdown
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    updateCountdown();
    $('.question').change(updateCountdown);
    $('.question').keyup(updateCountdown);
});

function updateCountdown() {
    var remaining = 100 - jQuery('.question').val().length;
    jQuery('.countdown').text(remaining + ' characters remaining.');
}
```

This works for me perfectly, although not in coffeescript.

Comment: I convert that to coffeescript, but it still doesn't show up. Does it have something to do with using the acts as commentable gem?

Comment: Most likely, but I'm not familiar with that plugin. This may help: http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/07/09/comments-on-acts-as-commentable/